# Variable condition in LINQ where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a database that I did not create and that I cannot modify. I need to run a linq query, but I need to pass in a variable in the `where` clause.

Columns in table: `AdvMonAM` (all bit), `AdvMonAM`, `AdvTueAM`, `AdvTuePM`, `AdvWedAM`, etc.

```
var column = "Adv" + dayOfWeek + time;
var employeesOnCall = from r in db.AdvOnCalls
                      where (variable column needed here) == true
                      select r.ChartEmployee;
```

If I hard code `r.AdvTueAM` it works perfectly, but `r.column == true` or `column == true` does not. I feel like this should be something easy, but I am stumped.

I am trying to find the employee(s) that are on call at a given time of day.

Comment: I know it isn't an answer, but this looks like an awful table design.

Comment: I looks like you are trying to do something very strange, I suggest you post the whole method to make it easier to figure out just what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the expression tree to represent the condition that you want manually, rather than using a lambda as you're trying to do:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEquals<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    string property,
    object valueToCompare)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(param, property),
        Expression.Constant(valueToCompare));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    return query.Where(lambda);
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
var employeesOnCall = db.AdvOnCalls.WhereEquals(column, true)
    .Select(adv => adv.ChartEmployee);
```

Comment: Tried this, but receiving this error: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Comment: @brown1455 As the error says, you need to define the method in a non-generic static class.  If the class is generic make it not generic, if the class isn't static make it static.

Comment: Sorry for that! now I am receiving this error: [InvalidOperationException: The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]' and 'System.Boolean'.] on var body = Expression.Equal(

Comment: @brown1455 Then pass in a nullable boolean, since that's the type of your variable.  If you want to throw out static typing it becomes your responsibility to pass in an object that is of the same type as the property itself.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, but I am not sure how to implement it with the code that you wrote above. Sorry, but I am still learning.

Comment: In my model I changed my fields to public bool AdvFriPM { get; set; } and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

The awful database design results in an awful solution:

```
where ( (column == "AdvMonAM" && AdvMonAM == 1)
        || (column == "AdvMonPM" && AdvMonPM == 1)
      )
```

And so on, for every field you add one condition. (I wasn't sure about the returned data type. If `bool`, remove the `== 1`)

Answer (score 2):

if the column in database can't be null:

```
string column = "Adv" + dayOfWeek + time;
var employeesOnCall = from r in db.AdvOnCalls
                      where (bool)r[column]
                      select r.ChartEmployee;
```

or:

```
string column = "Adv" + dayOfWeek + time;
var employeesOnCall = from r in db.AdvOnCalls
                      where r.Field<bool>(column)
                      select r.ChartEmployee;
```

if value of column can be null:

```
string column = "Adv" + dayOfWeek + time;
var employeesOnCall = from r in db.AdvOnCalls
                      where r.Field<bool?>(column)==true
                      select r.ChartEmployee;
```

Comment: Good option. Btw, the `== true` is not necessary.

Comment: @PatrickHofman you're right. I'm removing it. Plus, I'm assuming it is not LinqToSql and AdvOnCalls is a DataTable. If it's LinqToSql I would go with Reflection as in lomed's solution

Comment: As far as I know you shouldn't use reflection then, since it will break the possibility to generate the right SQL. It can cause massive loads on the database to process everything on the client.

Comment: The value of my column can be null so I tried your third option. However I received the following errors: 1) Instance argument: cannot convert from 'Intranet.Models.AdvOnCall' to 'System.Data.DataRow' 2) 'Intranet.Models.AdvOnCall' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field<T>(System.Data.DataRow, string)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) to enable you to do:

```
var column = "Adv" + dayOfWeek + time;
var employeesOnCall = db.AdvOnCalls
    .Where (column + " = 1")
    .Select(x => x.ChartEmployee);
```

...etc.

Answer (score 0):

- one option

  ```
  var column = "Adv" + dayOfWeek + time;
  var employeesOnCall = from r in db.AdvOnCalls
                        where GetPropByName(r, column)
                        select r.ChartEmployee;
  ```

  using this function:

  ```
  bool GetPropByName(AdvOnCall item, string column)
  {
     return (bool)item.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(item, null);
  }
  ```
- better option :):

  ```
  var employeesOnCall = from r in db.AdvOnCalls
                        where columnSwitch(r, dayOfWeek, time) 
                        select r.ChartEmployee;
  ```

  using this function:

  ```
  bool columnSwitch(AdvOnCall item, string dayOfWeek, string time)
  {
      if (time == "AM")
          if (dayOfWeek == "Mon")
              return item.AdvMonAM;
          else if (dayOfWeek == "Tue")
              return item.AdvTueAM;
          ...
       else // (time == "PM")
          if (dayOfWeek == "Mon")
              return item.AdvMonPM;
          else if (dayOfWeek == "Tue")
              return item.AdvTuePM;
          ...
  }
  ```

Comment: With the 1st option, I receive this error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'object.GetType()' on  return (bool)AdvOnCall.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(item, null);

Comment: Changed it to item.GetType() and typeof(AdvOnCall) and received a runtime error:     [NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean GetPropByName(Intranet.Models.AdvOnCall, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.]

Comment: I also tried the second option and received this runtime error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean columnSwitch(Intranet.Models.AdvOnCall, System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: @brown1455 None of these options will ever work, at a conceptual level, as a part of an EF query.  EF simply doesn't support some of the core operations used here.